# Simplifying Trig Expressions Using Identities.

Tags: trigonometry

My current attempt at Simplifying:

$\frac {\cos \theta}{1+ \sin \theta}$ + $\tan \theta $

I know that:

$\frac {\cos \theta}{1+ \sin \theta}$ = $\frac {1 - \sin \theta}{\cos \theta}$

and:

$\tan \theta $ = $\frac {\sin\theta}{\cos \theta}$

so:

$\frac {1 - \sin \theta}{\cos \theta}$ + $\frac {\sin\theta}{\cos \theta}$

Final simplifying step:

$\frac {1}{\cos \theta}$ = $\sec \theta$

Do I have the right idea? I'm not well versed enough make intuitive sense of this outcome. Any advise at all is much appreciated.

Comment: I think you are Correct

Comment: you are absolutely correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. One may show that the identity you mentioned is true:
$$\frac{\cos{\theta}}{1+\sin{\theta}} \equiv \frac{1-\sin{\theta}}{\cos{\theta}}$$

---

Let's multiply the numerator and denominator by $1-\sin{\theta}$:
$$\frac{\cos{\theta}\cdot (1-\sin{\theta})}{(1+\sin{\theta})(1-\sin{\theta})}=\frac{\cos{\theta}\cdot (1-\sin{\theta})}{1-\sin^2{\theta}}$$
Using the identity $\sin^2{\theta}+\cos^2{\theta} \equiv 1$, we have:
$$\frac{\cos{\theta}\cdot (1-\sin{\theta})}{\cos^2{\theta}}=\frac{1-\sin{\theta}}{\cos{\theta}}$$
Which is what we had to show.

---

Therefore, indeed:
$$\frac{1-\sin{\theta}}{\cos{\theta}}+\frac{\sin{\theta}}{\cos{\theta}}\equiv \sec{\theta}$$

Comment: I really appreciate the help. I have a similar problem that I'm actually stuck on. I'm not sure if it's appropriate to start another thread, so may I ask here?

Comment: Hi, it is more appropriate to ask a new question because it keeps the content on each post specific to the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

we have $$\frac{\cos(\theta)}{1+\sin(\theta)}+\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}=\frac{\cos^2(\theta)+\sin(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)}{\cos(\theta(1+\sin(\theta))}$$
the rest is for you!